# arabic query expansion - Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, arabic

using lucene, is there any way to expand arabic query with term synonyms ? I found something about wordnet but there is no code for arabic language.

sample code please ....

thanks in advance

Comment: Read this first.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arabic analysis funcitonality can be found in the [`org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar` package](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar).

If you are looking for arabic language stemming and such, you should use [`ArabicAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicAnalyzer.html).  You could also roll components of it into your own analyzer, in which case, [`ArabicStemFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicStemFilter.html) and [`ArabicNormalizationFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicNormalizationFilter.html) would be the key pieces.

If you are actually looking for synonym replacement, [`SynonymFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) should work fine in whatever language you please.